# Цветные символы в консольном приложении Windows

Tags: windows, консоль, c++

Как гуглить функции и есть ли такое вобще, что б выводить символы как в досе было, на определенную позицию и цветами разными?

Comment: Конечно есть: `SetConsoleCursorPosition` vs `SetConsoleTextAttribute` либо `WriteConsoleOutput`

Answer (score 2):

- [SetConsoleCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686025%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [SetConsoleTextAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Пример](http://www.mailsend-online.com/blog/setting-windows-console-text-colors-in-c.html)

Comment: На последний линк: "403 Forbidden"

Answer (score 1):

Да, конечно.

Используйте [`SetConsoleTextAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686047%28VS.85%29.aspx) и [`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Легко гуглится по запросу наподобие "[win32 console colors](http://www.google.com/search?q=win32+console+colors)"

Comment: Более того, [Цветные символы в консольном приложении Windows](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=Цветные+символы+в+консольном+приложении+Windows) :-)

Comment: оффтоп: @VladD, тебе @Spectre не оставил где-нить надпись: `Не трать мое время напрасно (c)`? :))

Comment: @mega: нет, а в каком случае она употребляется?

---
Если ты насчёт гугления, ТС явно спросил:

> Как гуглить функции

Comment: оффтоп: нет, я не по поводу вопроса, мне просто жест @Spectre напомнил аналогичный из [Время/In Time](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Время_(фильм,_2011))

Comment: @mega: А, понял. :) Фильм не видел. Не знаю пока, что делать с обрушившейся горой репутации — надо будет раздать крутым новым ответам, наверное.